# Segmentation fault in getting input to the array

Tags: c

This is a piece of code,hen I run this using gcc compiler i get segmentation fault.What is this actually and why is it happening in this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *left;
};
void funct(struct node *root,int num,int counter,int limit,int *arr)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
    root=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    }

    if(counter>=limit)
    {
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
        return;
    }
    root->number=num;
    counter++;
    funct(root->left,num+arr[0],counter,limit,arr);
    funct(root->right,num+arr[1],counter,limit,arr);

}
void getdata(struct node *root,int *res,int counter)
{
    while(root->left!=NULL&&root->right!=NULL)
    {
        getdata(root->left,res,counter);
        getdata(root->right,res,counter);
    }
    res[counter]=root->number;
}
int main()
{
    int t,i,n,arr[2],*res,size,j;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    j=0;
    while(j++<t)
    {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d %d",&arr[0],&arr[1]);
    size=pow(2,n-1);
    res=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    if(res==NULL)
    {
        printf("you got this one");
    }
    struct node *root=NULL;
    funct(root,0,0,n,arr);
    getdata(root,res,0);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {  
        printf("%d\t",res[i]);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here,I am using gcc compiler on ubuntu.I tried to trace the problem and think that have some problem with arr input in scanf.

Comment: 1. Indent your code. 2. Use the debugger to find the location of the segmentation fault

Comment: Use some debugger like gdb, and see where the segmentation fault is happening and why.

Comment: Where are you allocating `root`? What are `func` and `getdata`? "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 4):

You are using `malloc`s return without checking for failure. If `size = pow(2, n-1)` is too big, `malloc` will fail and return a null pointer. Dereferencing a null pointer often results in a segfault. Error checking example:

```
res=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
if(res){
struct node *root=NULL;
funct(root,0,0,n,arr);
getdata(root,res,0);
}
else {//handle error}
```

Comment: @user2738777 More details please. What are you trying to do? What value of `size` are you failing at?

Comment: In the test cases which i used, size of n is 3 and 4.Also i checked whether malloc is returning null or not, but it was not returning NULL value.